# Custom Ruby Enumerator supporting offset

Tags: ruby, each

I have the following **Query** class that behaves like an Enumerator

```
class Query
  include Enumerable
  # ...
  def each(&block)
    @results.each do |id|
      yield @repo.find(id)
    end  
  end
end
```

With the above code I can build the following loops:

```
query_all.each do |x|
...
query_all.each_with_index(1) do |x, idx|
```

Just defining the **each** function, I got for free **each_with_index**. However, what I cannot get working is this:

```
query_all.each.with_index(1) do |x, idx|
   puts x
end

 Failure/Error: query_all.each.with_index(1) do |tag, idx|
 LocalJumpError:
   no block given (yield)
```

As far as I know the **LocalJumpError** is usually related with a missing block (which I am providing), so I am not sure if I am missing some parameter in my **each**, or if this time I must define a new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you're defining a block inside the `each`, which yields inside. Each can be called without a block (which is what you're doing after). You should just return the each result (without invoking the block) if the method is called without a block.

```
class Query
  include Enumerable
  # ...
  def each(&block)
    results = @results.map {|id| @repo.find(id)}
    if block
      results.each(&block)
    else 
      results.each
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Humm..You are very smart!! Good! :)

Comment: wow! very nice trick generating a new complete Enumerator to spare writing more functions in my Query class. I added the parenthesis to your example because without them I got a warning.

Comment: @ArupRakshit which one was the method you mentioned I should implement inside Query? could you provide a sample gist? Maybe next time, I will not be able to generate a temporal nested enumerator